# Dynamic element height to match background cover dimensions

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm using the following CSS to set a cover background image on an element:

```
.bg {
    background: url(images/kitteh1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 200px;
}
```

What is the right, CSS-only, way of having the element size exactly match that of the background image, such that the image first takes up 100% width, and then takes as much height as necessary to fit the original aspect ratio?

Here's the playground: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ek812c/

Comment: @GabrielSNM - that just hides the background

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/e5ek812c/2/

Comment: AFAIK, the CSS will never be aware of the image size. What you can do, however, is set a `padding-top` to the image's ratio: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ek812c/1/

Comment: @blex - perfect solution! please add this as a proper answer so I can upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the CSS will never be aware of the image size.
What you can do, however, is set a `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` to the image's ratio (height is`56.25%` of the width here).

**Explanation**

`padding-top`, when set as a percentage, uses the element's width as a reference (`100%`). Unlike `height`.

```css
.a { background-color: #ddd; }
.bg {
    background: url(https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/images/kitteh1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.c { background-color: #aaa; }
```

```html
<div class="a">hello</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="c">bye</div>
```

#### Updated JS Fiddle